# link not working in Chrome but it works in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, broken-links

I am facing a weird issue that my menu has stopped working in `chrome 66.0.3359.139`. My menu has overlay/lightbox screen for the submenu. I just noticed that user is able to click only first column's submenu and rest of the submenu items are not clickable.

My site's top menu is using pointer event as the following code, I am not sure is it the causing the issue or not. Besides, this menu was working fine before chrome's `66.0.3359.139` version update. It still working fine in Firefox and Safari.

```
a.disabled{
pointer-events:auto;
@media #{$medium-only, $small-only} {
  pointer-events:none;
}}
```

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvpVxr

Comment: Your CodePen appears broken. Can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (in the question itself), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: And, include the code right here, in a "code snippet" instead of at a 3rd party site.